# iOS8の CustomKeyboard で、UIDatePicker を配置すると実機上で固まる

Tags: ios, ios8, uipickerview, ios-app-extension

現在、 AppExtension のカスタムキーボードを `UIDatePicker` を使って作成しています。

シミュレータ上では `UIDatePicker` は正常に動作するのですが、いざ実機で操作してみると、
**`UIDatePicker` を操作した(回した)時点で固まってしまいます。**

カスタムキーボードのテンプレートに追加したコードは、

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView* view = (UIView*) [[UINib nibWithNibName:@"KeyboardView" bundle:NULL] instantiateWithOwner:self options:NULL][0];

    view.frame = self.inputView.frame;

    [self.inputView addSubview:view];
} 

- (IBAction)nextButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    [self advanceToNextInputMode];
}
```

のみで、 `viewDidLoad` の中で、以下の `KeyboardView.xib` を読み込んでいます。

KeyboardView.xib:  
[image: KeyboardView.xib]

この現象は `UIPickerView` でも同様に発生するようです。

原因や対策など、何かないでしょうか？

問題のプロジェクトを以下に貼ります。
https://mega.co.nz/#!zBInkIzY!Obt7elqi3pKkVPRplkI1knsMEbz5bUyhdAzn4d3iRX4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

検証しましたら、フルアクセスを許可することで、スムーズに動作することが確認できました。

#### フルアクセス許可の表示方法

`info.plist` > `NSExtension` > `NSExtensionAttributes` > `RequestsOpenAccess` を `YES` へ変更

#### 環境

- Xcode 6.1.1
- iOS 8.1
- iPhone 6

Comment: フルアクセスを許可することで無事、正常に動くようになりました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score -3):

回答になっておりませんが、私も同様の現象にハマりました。
解決策がわからずUITableViewに逃げました。

Comment: 何を試した上であきらめたかや、どのようにUITableViewでUIDatePicker/UIPickerViewと同様のUIを実現したかを説明すれば、十分役立つ回答になると思います。本当に「回答ではない」回答であれば、コメントの方が適切、ということでマイナス票が付いているのだと思います (他の人の質問にコメントするには信用度をためる必要がありますが)。なお、回答は後から[edit]できます。